# Как правильно сравнить заменить слово в массиве?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив со словами и массив объектов с "неправильными словами" и их заменами т.е. правильными словами. Мне нужно найти в массиве неправильное слово и заменить его с учетом локали (переменная locale).

Первый и основной массив выглядит так

```
let e = ["Строки", "Строчка", "В строке", "На строке", "На донышке"]
```

Второй массив объектов содержит массив списка плохих слов и правильных, на которые нужно заменить плохие слова в первом массиве.

```
let o = [{ "ru": "Строка", "en": "String", "wrong": ["В строке", "В строчке"] }, { "ru": "Дно", "en": "Bottom", "wrong": ["На дне", "На донышке"] }]
```

Есть так же переменная которая определена как

```
let locale = "ru"
```

Мне нужно сделать следующее:
Пройтись по всему массиву (е), если в массиве найдено слово из `o[*].wrong`, то заменить его на `o[*][locale]` в основном массиве, должно получиться следующее:

```
e = ["Строки", "Строчка", "**Строка**", "На строке", "**Дно**"]
```

Comment: Да, я что то ошибся =)

Comment: Исправил в вопросе)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В исходном массиве `wrong` изменил всё на lowerCase(), чтобы не париться с регистром (иначе будет заменять только точные совпадения).

```js
let e = ["Строки", "Строчка", "В строке", "На строке", "На донышке"];

let o = [
  { "ru": "Строка", "en": "String", "wrong": ["в строке", "в строчке"] },
  { "ru": "Дно", "en": "Bottom", "wrong": ["на дне", "на донышке"] }
];

let locale = "ru";

for (let i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  let searching = e[i].toLowerCase();
  
  let obj = o.find( obj => obj.wrong.includes(searching) );
  
  if (obj) e[i] = "**" + obj[locale] + "**";
}

console.log( e );
```

`.includes(элемент)` проверяет, есть ли такой элемент в массиве, возвращает true / false.

`.find(функция)` возвращает первый найденный элемент, для которого вызванная функция вернула true.

---

Если предстоит много таких замен, можно перестроить структуру `o`, чтобы сразу взять нужное слово, так:

```js
let e = ["Строки", "Строчка", "В строке", "На строке", "На донышке"];

let o = [
  { "ru": "Строка", "en": "String", "wrong": ["в строке", "в строчке"] },
  { "ru": "Дно", "en": "Bottom", "wrong": ["на дне", "на донышке"] }
];

let locale = "ru";

let o2 = rearrange_o(o);
/* {
 *   "в строке": {ru: "Строка, en: "String"},
 *   "в строчке": {ru: "Строка, en: "String"},
 *   ...
 */

for (let i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  let wrong_word = o2[ e[i].toLowerCase() ];
  if (wrong_word) e[i] = "**" + wrong_word[locale] + "**";
}

console.log( e );

/***/
function rearrange_o(o) {
  let result = {};
  
  for (let obj of o) {
    let words = {ru: obj.ru, en: obj.en};
    // Это чтобы не создавать лишние объекты для каждого слова.
    
    for (let wrong_word of obj.wrong) {
      result[wrong_word] = words; // Они будут ссылаться на один и тот же words
    }
  }
  
  document.body.innerHTML = `<pre>${ JSON.stringify(result, true, 2) }</pre>`;
  
  return result;  
}
```

---

---

К слову, помимо массива... `wrong` может хранить и регулярные выражения) Хотя в сложных комбиранциях слов, с массивами будет легче работать.

```js
let e = ["Строки", "Строчка", "В строке", "На строке", "На донышке"];

let o = [
  { "ru": "Строка", "en": "String", "wrong": /^в строч?ке$/i },
  { "ru": "Дно", "en": "Bottom", "wrong": /^на д(?:н|онышк)е$/i }
];

let locale = "ru";

for (let i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  let obj = o.find( obj => obj.wrong.test(e[i]) );
  if (obj) e[i] = "**" + obj[locale] + "**";
}

console.log( e );
```

Comment: Все гуд, спасибо!!!

Comment: @webphp Такая ошибка может появится только если где-то в массивах забыли указать word. Для начала можно заменить эту строчку на `o.find( obj => console.log(obj.wrong) )` - посмотреть, что выводит.

Comment: Да я опять указал obj.tags вместо obj.wrong =) Сейчас все супер! Еще раз спасибо!